# Django integrity error and not loading onetoone table on sign up form

Tags: python, django, forms, models

Hello everyone thanks for your help.

I have made a sign up form with django. As of now when i fill in all of the fields in the form it allows me to submit, the new user is created, then i get the error below

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: slug_trade_app_userprofile.user_id
```

Also in my models (below) i have a onetoone relations with the UserProfile model and for some reason none of that data is stored to the database, it only gets the username/pass/first/last. It appears to me that for some reason it submits the form the trys to submit again causing the UNIQUE issue. Not sure what i did wrong here, thanks for your help.

Blow is my code

views.py

```
def signup(request):

signed_in = False

if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)

    print(user_form.is_valid())
    print(profile_form.is_valid())

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user

        if 'profile_picture' in request.FILES:
            profile.profile_picture = request.FILES['profile_picture']

        profile.save()

        signed_in = True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request, 'my_app/signup.html',
                        {'user_form':user_form,
                         'profile_form':profile_form,
                         'signed_in':signed_in})
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/profile_pictures', blank=True )
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    on_off_campus = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                            default="on",
                            choices=CAMPUS_STATUS)
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profile_picture', 'bio', 'on_off_campus')
```

signup.html

```
{% if registered %}
    <h1>Thank you for registering!</h1>
{% else %}
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" name="" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: I suppose the `username` is the unique value of User Model. you should check whether the provided username exists before saving it

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Do you have a signal that creates a profile when the user is created?

Comment: alasdair i am not sure. i dont think so basically everything i have is what is there

lemayzeur that was the first thing i did. I am only using usernames that are unique when i input